# Can we create SQL Server CE's installation with Windows Installer?

Tags: windows-installer, sql-server-ce

By just adding 7 files to our project and publishing it with ClickOnce, Installer was installing SQL Server CE if it's not installed on the machine before installation of our program.

Can we install SQL Server CE with Windows Installer if it's not installed before? If we can, how? (I mean, how can we add its installation to Setup Project in Visual Studio?)

Comment: See an approach here http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html

Comment: I've looked up the page you sent. However, my Setup Wizard doesn't have the third part. "Choose project outputs to include" isn't there??

Comment: Which VS version and Setup Wizard?

Comment: VS 2010 Pro. How am I going to look Setup Wizard's version?